# Convert QuadMesh generated by pcolormesh to an RGBA array

Tags: python, matplotlib

Lets say I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
z = np.sum(np.meshgrid(x,y), 0)

qm = plt.pcolormesh(x, y, z[:-1, :-1])
```

`qm` is now a [QuadMesh](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh) object. Now, I want to covert this QuadMesh to an RGBA array, in this case a 9x9x4 array giving the red, green, blue, and alpha values at each point.

The QuadmEsh object does have a `to_rgba()` subroutine, but I am having trouble interpreting the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh.to_rgba). `to_rgba()` requires some *x* value, where x is described as "a 1-D or 2-D sequence of scalars, and the corresponding ndarray of rgba values will be returned, based on the norm and colormap set for this ScalarMappable". But I'm not sure what any of that means...

Comment: For a start, your code does not do what you think it does. But apart from that: Why do you need this method, which is rarely needed? What is the goal you try to achieve? It sounds a bit like an X-Y problem, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I had a typo in the assignment for `z`, I assume that's what your referencing (fixed now). Ultimately I am trying to find an answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884579/python-pcolormesh-with-separate-alpha-value-for-each-bin that does not involve drawing individual rectangles. My idea being if I can extract an RGBA image, I can the edit the alpha value and replot with imshow.

Comment: That is indeed the only application of to_rgba() I can think of (but I am happy to learn about other uses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not convinced that there is no better way to address this before plotting pcolormesh but I assume this is what you intend to do:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
z = np.sum(np.meshgrid(x,y), 0)
    
qm1 = ax1.pcolormesh(x, y, z[:-1, :-1], cmap="plasma")
ax1.axes.set_aspect("equal")

#retrieve rgba values of the quadmesh object
rgbas = qm1.to_rgba(qm1.get_array().reshape(z[:-1, :-1].shape))

#modify the alpha values
rgbas[:, :, 3] = np.linspace(0, 1, z[:-1, :-1].size).reshape(z[:-1, :-1].shape)

#plot back with imshow 
qm2 = ax2.imshow(rgbas, origin="lower")

ax1.set_title("pcolormesh")
ax2.set_title("imshow after alpha modification")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: This works! I also ended up finding an answer to my original question (how to set alpha of individual square in pcolormesh) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100747/changing-facecolor-alpha-value-gives-unwanted-edges-matplotlib-pcolormesh
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177718/use-a-variable-to-set-alpha-opacity-in-a-colormap