# Changing Opacity by a function

Tags: python-3.x, scatter-plot, opacity, scatter3d

I have created a 3d scatter plot that changes colour based around a separate variable, Intensity. Ideally I would change the opacity so that the lower intensity colours are less visible. To do this I created a separate function that should return a different value, to be placed as the alpha value, for each intensity value based upon its size compared to the max intensity value. When I run this though all scatter points receive the first opacity value I put into my function.
I can not spot the error and would appreciate if someone could cast there eye over it.

Section of code that generates plot and opacity function:

```
'''
Trial for opacity differentiation
'''
   
def OP(b):
    for i in range(len(b)):
        Imx = np.amax(b) 
        print(Imx)
        if b[i] > .9*Imx:
            return .9
        elif b[i] <= .9*Imx:
            return 0.1
        else:
            return 0
    
'''
3d Colour scatterplot of Intensity
'''
def hlkplt(filename):
    h = np.linspace(0,4,9)
    l = np.linspace(0,4,9)
    k = np.linspace(0,4,9)
    I = []
    for j in range(len(h)):
        for i in range(len(l)):
            for n in range(len(k)):
                IStot = Int2(filename,h[j],l[i],k[n])
                p = IStot.real
                I.append(p)
    

    
    b = np.array(I)
    
    hh, ll, kk = np.meshgrid(h,l,k)
    
    cm = plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn')
    fig = plt.figure()

    ax3D = plt.axes(projection = '3d')    
    ax3D.set_xlabel('h plane')
    ax3D.set_ylabel('l plane')
    ax3D.set_zlabel('k plane')
           
    p3d = ax3D.scatter(hh,ll,kk, s = 30, c = b,alpha =OP(b), marker ='o',label = filename)

    plt.legend()
    cbar = plt.colorbar(p3d)
    cbar.set_label('Scattering Intensity of neutrons')
    plt.show()
    
    return
```

The Int2 function just produces a complex number which is turned real and placed into a list

Comment: Several problems. First, OP(b) returns a value, not an array, so of course, all points have the same alpha value. BUT: This prevented you from getting an error message because scatter does not take arrays as inputs for the alpha value. You can either plot each point individually with its individual alpha value or transform the RGB value for color into an [RGBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65635914/8881141) value.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.T. So OP(b) would always use my first, and highest intensity, and therefore return .9? I think I'll try transforming my RGB value into an RGBA value as it should be more efficient.

Comment: Your OP(b) function returns one value, not necessarily 0.9, even if the input is an array. You can rewrite it that it returns a numpy array to feed it into the RGBA array. I think this will be the fastest solution.